# Excel, deleted data recovery

Tags: security, microsoft-excel, privacy, metadata, microsoft-excel-2003

How do I make sure that in Excel, if I delete some sensitive data and send the file around this is not recoverable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specificy which version of Excel you have. This is the link for Excel XP/2003:
[Office 2003/XP Add-in: Remove Hidden Data](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=144e54ed-d43e-42ca-bc7b-5446d34e5360&displaylang=en)

EDIT: See this [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100375931033.aspx) for 2007.